# How to scroll-draw SVG in two directions at same time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Can't seem to figure out how this "T-junction" would draw to left and right at same time instead of first to left, then to right.

What I've been trying to do;

```
<path class="path" fill="none" stroke="white"  stroke-width="6" id="triangle" d="M 450,50 L 450,200 L350,200 550,200" />
```

JS-fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/ewf9soax/

Thanks in advance

Comment: simplest to create two paths, an L and a backwards L and then run your scrolling code on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is a slight tweak to your path definition.

```
d="M 450,50 L 450,200 L350,200
   M 450,50 L 450,200 L550,200"
```

As Robert suggested, we split the path into two L-shaped subpaths. One going to the left, and one to the right.  And since dash patterns apply to individual subpaths, and not the path as a whole, it'll automatically work.

You may want to update your `stroke-dasharray` length to compensate for the fact that the subpaths are now shorter than the original path.

```js
// Get the id of the <path> element and the length of <path>
var triangle = document.getElementById("triangle");
var length = triangle.getTotalLength();

// The start position of the drawing
triangle.style.strokeDasharray = length;

// Hide the triangle by offsetting dash. Remove this line to show the triangle before scroll draw
triangle.style.strokeDashoffset = length;

// Find scroll percentage on scroll (using cross-browser properties), and offset dash same amount as percentage scrolled
window.addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
var scrollpercent = (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);

  var draw = length * scrollpercent;
  
  // Reverse the drawing (when scrolling upwards)
  triangle.style.strokeDashoffset = length - draw;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

#mySVG {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0:;
  width: 900px;
  height: 810px;
  margin-left:-450px;background-color:green;left: 50%;z-index: 100000;
}
```

```html
<svg class ="path" id="mySVG">
  <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="white"  stroke-width="6" id="triangle" d="M 450,50 L 450,200 L350,200
                                                                                   M 450,50 L 450,200 L550,200" />


  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

[Updated fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ewf9soax/1/)